# Send SAML Assertion from SalesForce to Connected App

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

So I've added a connected APP to SalesForce. The connected app links to an external web application.

When a user clicks on connected app via App Launcher or top right corner drop down, this is what I would like to happen:
1: SalesForce forwards session SAML Token or SAML Request to external application SAML endpoint / Identity Provider 
2: External Web Applications SAML endpoint / Identity provider authenticates SAML Token or request
3: External Applications receives SAML Assertion and validates. Logs user into External Application.

Is this possible?

Alternatively, maybe it's possible for this workflow to work if SalesForce is used as the Identity Provider in Step 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by Bernhard gave me the info I needed to post SAML Assertion from my connected app to my external application.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_google_connapp.htm

Comment: Thomas: The implementation guide has changed. Could you please share how to "o post SAML Assertion from my connected app to my external application"?

Comment: One idea is to configure Salesforce as an IdP, then make the canvas app a SP as described in Salesforce Help doc: Configure SSO from Salesforce to Google Apps (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_examples_google.htm&type=5). 

I'd appreciate if you can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If SalesForce is used as the SAMLv2 IdP (Identity Provider - issuing party) then this is possible. Your app will act as the SAMLv2 SP (Service Provider - relying party). Authentication always happens at the IdP in Web SSO. Only if account linking is performed (when you have different identity silos), then authentication happens on both entities, otherwise the identities can not be linked.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard.
Any idea how I can get SF to actually post SAML Assertion to the  "Connected App" /  "Service Provider" I have setup?
I followed this tutorial but it is a bit light on explaining if the SAML is actually posted to my Service provider when I click the APP link in SF.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=0

Comment: potentially https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_google_connapp.htm sheds more light.
As statued SF IdP perform IdP initated SSO. This means the IdP directly sends the SAML assertion, using the configured 'binding' (most likely HTTP POST binding) to the configure ACS (Assertion Consumer Service) endpoint/URL

You could use SAML trace plugin for Firefox to inspect the SAML protocol messages being sent

Comment: That gmail connected app example gave me all the info I needed to post SAML Assertion from Connected App to my external app.